# Coloring Entire Table instead of cells

Tags: html, powershell

I have a table with 3 columns, first has a name of a role, second and third have either "EXISTS" or "MISSING" in the cells as to indicate if that role is on the server the column represents.

This code is coloring my entire table green instead of the cells with "EXISTS" in them. I'm not too versed in html, but I know the " < t d > " tags indicate the cell. I got this code from searching endless links on "how to color-code a html table powershell"

```
foreach {if($_ -like "*<td>EXISTS</td>*") {
            $_ -replace "<td>", "<td bgcolor=green>"
         } elseif ($_ -like "*<td>MISSING</td>*") {
            $_ -replace "<td>", "<td bgcolor=red>"
         } else {
            $_
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by fixing the

```
-replace <td>
```

with

```
-replace <td>MISSING</td>
```

Hope this helps people out!